# Where is ReplaceService in python client library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I wanna create Cloud Function so each time a specific log passed to cloud function, it would restart/redeploy. However, i need ReplaceService to redeploy it. What I got so far is using UpdateService, and i think its a different thing.

I believe its a ReplaceService since, when I manually redeploy, the log is ReplaceService.
[image]

Howerver, i dont find it in the client library.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-run/samples/generated_samples

So far i can do this in GC Function. I trigger it by passing 'MauCumiKering' (its just example).

```
import base64
from google.cloud import run_v2

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
      """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
      Args:
            event (dict): Event payload.
            context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
      """
      try:
            pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
            if 'MauUdangKering' in pubsub_message:
                  print(type(pubsub_message))
            elif 'MauCumiKering' in pubsub_message:
                  redeploy_cloud_run_container("projects/my-project/locations/asia-southeast1/services/my-service")
            else:
                  print(pubsub_message)
      except Exception as e:
            print('Sorry error', e)

def redeploy_cloud_run_container(service_name):
      client = run_v2.ServicesClient()
      service = client.get_service(name=service_name)
      request = run_v2.UpdateServiceRequest(service=service)

      operation = client.update_service(request=request)
      response = operation.result()
      print(response)
```

But its not redeploying the cloud run container (although there is a log for UpdateService).

Comment: UpdateService does redeploying, but only if there is an update in YAML/var/etc. I need smth like ReplaceService in python client google cloud library where it always be redeploying even if its not different than previous revision

Comment: Redeploy a Cloud Run service based on a specific log message in a Cloud Function. However, there's no `ReplaceService` method, you can achieve it using the `update\_service` method with the `rollout\_strategy` set to `REPLACE`. This effectively replaces the service with a new revision, triggering a redeployment. Remember to wait for the update operation to finish and ensure your Cloud Function has the necessary permissions.

Comment: @Chanpols thanks. can you provide simple snippet where I should put that param in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Redeploy a Cloud Run service based on a specific log message in a Cloud Function. However, there's no `ReplaceService` method, you can achieve it using the `update_service` method with the `rollout_strategy` set to `REPLACE`. This effectively replaces the service with a new revision, triggering a redeployment. Remember to wait for the update operation to finish and ensure your Cloud Function has the necessary permissions.

```
def redeploy_cloud_run_container(service_name):
    client = run_v2.ServicesClient()
    service = client.get_service(name=service_name)

    request = run_v2.UpdateServiceRequest(
        service=service,
        rollout_strategy="REPLACE"
    )

    operation = client.update_service(request=request)
    response = operation.result()
    print(response)
```

References:

1. UpdateService method:

- [Python Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference)
- [Specific section on rollout_strategy](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/python)

2. Cloud Run Admin API:

- [gcloud run deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy)

This might be useful if you require more granular control than what the standard client library offers.

Comment: I got this error "Sorry error Unknown field for UpdateServiceRequest: rollout_strategy"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating some random metadate with every revision update so it forces a redeploy with each update request too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).